# Updated Dynamics GP AddIn Duplicates Menu Item

Tags: dynamics-gp

I am working with a GP add-in created in visual studio and deployed to the AddIns folder - note this is not originally my project. The add-in places a menu item on the Payables Batch Entry window's Additional menu to open a custom window. I changed a parameter's default state which is unrelated to the menu item. I then renamed the existing DLL in the AddIns folder and copied the newly built one in. When I view the Additional menu there are now two items for this window and both open the window.

Would you have any thoughts on why there are two menu items or perhaps have some direction of where I should continue investigating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamics GP will load every dll present in the AddIns folder into it's execution run-time. So if you left a copy of the old dll in the folder, even if it was renamed, it will continue to be loaded. I suspect you are seeing the link in duplicate because there are still two dlls in the folder being loaded.

Comment: I had renamed it "*.dll no batch delete" thinking that was good enough as the system no longer recognized it as a DLL file. However, going on your suggestion I renamed it removing the "dll" all together and it resolved the issue. Thanks.